# Sentiment analysis in PHP?

Tags: php, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

Since both OpenNlp and StanfordCoreLibraries are java implementation, is it possible to integrate with PHP developement?
if so can u guys provide me with some resource links or small examples.
Thank you

Comment: You might consider using a RESTful API for sentiment analysis. There are quite a few of them on Mashape: https://www.mashape.com/search?query=sentiment

Comment: @vpekar i have heard about RESTful API, that means RESTFUL API will serve as SENTIMENT ANALYSIS ENGINE and using PHP developement as front-end i will query the engine for analysis of sentiments? 
M i right? 

Can you please provide some links for such implementation?

Comment: Yes, you'd be accessing a Sentiment Analysis system via an API. You'd better take a look at several and choose one that suits your needs (and has reasonable accuracy on your type of texts). E.g., you might choose one if you need the overall sentiment of a document, and another if you want sentiment attached to specific phrases in a document. Just go through the list of APIs I posted above.

Answer (score 3):

For Stanford CoreNLP, the easiest thing to do is probably to interface between PHP and Java using Apache Thrift.  There's an [Apache Thrift Server for CoreNLP](https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/stanford-thrift) by Diane Napolitano.

Answer (score 1):

You could do worse than looking at [Ian Barber's excellent PHP/ir article on Bayesian opinion mining](http://www.phpir.com/bayesian-opinion-mining)